# Calculate julian day for one year in fortran

Tags: fortran

I want to calculate julian day for just one year (not from 4713 BC!). For example, If it is 3 of March, it will give as a result the number 62 If February has 28 days, and 63 if it has 29. Until now, I have written the following code in Fortran 95, which unfortunately gives wrong result. Could you please help me debug it?

```
program task
    !============================    
    !filename: task.f95

    implicit none  

    integer day, sum_month, i, month(12), jd, year, mon  

    month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]    

    write(6,*) "Give day"    
    read(5,*) day    
    write(6,*) "Give mon"    
    read(5,*) mon    
    write(6,*) "Give year"    
    read(5,*) year 

    sum_month = 0  

    if (mod(year,4)==0 .and. mod(year,100)/=0) then     
        do i = month(1), mon-1    
            sum_month = sum_month + month(1) + day + 1    
        end do    
    else    
        do i = month(1), mon-1    
            sum_month = sum_month + month(1) + day    
        end do    
    end if  

    write(6,*) sum_month   

end program task
```

Comment: I don't want to jump to conclusions without knowing exactly what your expectations are around actual and desired results, but there are an awful lot of `month(1)`s in there.

Comment: Are you even sure that this program is compiling with `etos` not defined anywhere and `implicit none`?

Comment: Do not change your question substantially after you receive answers. You should a new question. You can use edits for clarifications, more code and so on, but do not change existing code substantially. Use all debugging options your compiler has. For gfortran use at least `-g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all`.

Answer (score 3):

This loop

```
do i = month(1), mon-1    
    sum_month = sum_month + month(1) + day + 1    
end do
```

and the other one like it, is seriously broken.  Every time you call it `month(1)==31` and `mon` is likely to be between `1` and `12` (inclusive).  So the program will try to execute, for (for example) `mon==12`

```
do i = 31,12
```

and under the rules of Fortran this loop will execute `0` times.  I'm almost certain you should write:

```
do i = 1, mon-1
   sum_month = sum_month + month(i) ...
```

Fix that, sort out the rest of your code, and you'll probably fix it without further help.

EDIT:

Your code is getting worse !  Well, it was getting worse until VladimirF rolled back your latest changes.  Do as he and I have suggested.  Ask a new question concerning your current problem.

You're not being careful enough about the difference between your variable `mon` (which you use to hold the number of the month input by the user) and `month` (which is the array you use to hold the number of days in each month of the year).

These statements

```
write(6,*) "Give mon"    
read(5,*) month(i)
```

will read the value which belongs in `mon` and put it into `month(i)`.  Or rather, that's what it tries to do but at that place in the code `i` doesn't have any value and the code attempts to write it into some arbitrary location in the computer's memory -- this is what a segmentation fault is and this is a great way to generate one.  Don't do that !

You're going to have a problem later too, when your code reaches

```
do i = 1, month(i)-1
```

Go back to the top of my answer and ask yourself *What value does* `month(i)` *have when this line of code is executed ?*

Comment: Thank you very much! So, you suggest than mon will be an array (mon(i))?